# Kubernetes error while creating mount source path : file exists

Tags: kubernetes

after re-deploying my kubernetes statefulset, the pod is now failing due to error while creating mount source path

```
'/var/lib/kubelet/pods/1559ef17-9c48-401d-9a2f-9962a4a16151/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-6b9ac265-d0ec-4564-adb2-1c7b3f6631ca/mount': mkdir /var/lib/kubelet/pods/1559ef17-9c48-401d-9a2f-9962a4a16151/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-6b9ac265-d0ec-4564-adb2-1c7b3f6631ca/mount: file exists
```

I'm assuming this is because the persistent volume/PVC already exists and so it cannot be created, but I thought that was the point of the statefulset, that the data would persist and you could just mount it again?   How should I fix this?
Thanks.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: foo-service
    spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      ports:
      - name: http 
        port: 80
      selector:
        app: foo-app
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: StatefulSet
    metadata:
      name: foo-statefulset
      namespace: foo
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: foo-app
      serviceName: foo-app
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: foo-app
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: foo-service-account
          containers:
          - name: foo
            image: blahblah
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            volumeMounts:
            - name: foo-data
              mountPath: "foo"
            - name: stuff
              mountPath: "here"
            - name: config
              mountPath: "somedata"
          volumes:      
          - name: stuff
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: stuff-pvc
          - name: config
            configMap:
              name: myconfig
      volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: foo-data
        spec:
          accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
          storageClassName: "foo-storage"
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 2Gi
```

Comment: do you have access to the node logs? This looks like an error there, reading around i see some resolved similar by restarting the worker node

Comment: Have you resolved this? If yes, please share the steps on how did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I've got the same issue. I've created 2 PersistentVolume with the same volumeHandle which was causing the issue. I’ve redeployed PersistentVolume with a unique name to resolve the issue. You can refer to the comment "make sure this volumeid is unique in the cluster" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume#mount-file-share-as-a-persistent-volume